# Hide UITableView when searchResultsTableView displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.2

I have a `UITableView` with a `searchDisplayController` implemented. I have

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

When I enter text in the search field, the search results are displaying fine, but as the background of the resultant table is transparent, I am seeing my `tableview` and on the `tableview` the search result table is displayed. I want to hide the `tableView` when the searchField began editing. I have tried

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [tableView setHidden:YES];
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString 
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

But it hides the searchBar with the tableView. How to fix it?

Comment: Where u add UISearchBar??? on UITableView ???

Comment: yes, I have dragged a UISearchDisplayController and added the searchbar to the tableView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947858/adding-uisearchbar-programmatically-to-uitableview/6948477#6948477

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i know that you add `searchDisplayController` on `UITableView`.

Remove it Please and Add your `UISearchDisplayController` on your **View Controller** not on `UITableView`, beacuse if you hide `UITableView` then `UISearchDisplayController` also hide because you added UISearchDisplayController on `UITableView`.

**Thanks :)**

Answer (score 2):

You can setup the data source for the `tableView` in such way that it returns 0 sections when the search interface is visible:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *) tableView
{
    if (self.searchDisplayController.active && 
        (tableView != self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableview))
        return 0; // return 0 for bottom table view if search interface is active
    else
        return <your usual number of sections>
}
```

And then instead of hiding your table view, you could do `[tableView reloadData]` to hide all content. Then after search is finished, reload the table view once more to show the content again.

Reloading the table view will reset all the table view cells and the content offset of the table view though, so it may be not a good idea to do that in some cases.

Alternatively, you could try to iterate through all of the table view's visible cells and hide them like that:

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in tableView.visibleCells)
{
     cell.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: I thought of this processes earlier, but i needed a simpler solution. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

first of all make the table outlet and connect it with Table
then Try this line of code

```
tableView.hidden=TRUE;
```

it will work....

Comment: tableView is already an outlet and is connected.and i was doing the same thing you have posted.