# How to use search bar in tableview using this code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

How to search `cell.textLabel.text` value with `textfield`? I am using this code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


UITextField* tf = nil ;
switch ( indexPath.row ) {
    case 0: {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Name" ;
        tf = nameField_ = [self makeTextField:self.name placeholder:@"sathish"]; 
        [cell addSubview:nameField_];
        break ;
    }
    case 1: {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Address" ;
        tf = addressField_ = [self makeTextField:self.address placeholder:@"example@gmail.com"];
        [cell addSubview:addressField_];
        break ;
    }
    case 2: {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Password" ;
        tf = passwordField_ = [self makeTextField:self.password placeholder:@"Required"];
        [cell addSubview:passwordField_];
        break ;
    }
    case 3: {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Description" ;
        tf = descriptionField_ = [self makeTextField:self.description placeholder:@"My Gmail Account"];
        [cell addSubview:descriptionField_];
        break ;
    }
}

tf.frame = CGRectMake(120, 12, 170, 30);    

[tf addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldFinished:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];    

tf.delegate = self ;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You mean, when you enter text in searchbar. It should populate the data in the tableview right??

Comment: how to search cell.textlabel.text value without array..

Comment: My point is, do you want to pass this cell.textlabel.text value in the search bar??

Comment: yes.have to pass the value.then only able to search it..

Comment: What i meant is UISearchbar is outside the UITableView? not inside the UITableView. Is it like that??

Comment: Yes.It is outside the UITableview.

Comment: Ok, It is possible to search. But the think here is you cannot pass the text value inside cellforrowatindexPath of UITableView to UISearchbar. But in other method like viewDidLoad it is possibe. If this helps you then let me know so that will show the code how to implement the same.

Comment: Already i did that one.its working perfect.need is have to pass the Text value.

Comment: But you cannot pass in UITableView. Even, if you try to set just simple hardecode value also. It will not set. Why you want to pass Value inside UITableView method??

Answer (score 1):

Basic steps:

1. Declare and initialize UISearchBar in your class
2. Declare and initialize the UISearchDisplayController
3. Add the searchBar to the your tableView
4. Implement the UISearchDisplayController delegate methods

this popular link you get more idea

[Adding UISearchBar Programmatically to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947858/adding-uisearchbar-programmatically-to-uitableview)