# How do I create a UISearchController since UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uisearchcontroller, ios9.1

There is NO UISearchController in IB, only the UISearchDisplayController; where do I find docs on creating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation;

> Important: UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UISearchDisplayDelegate is also deprecated.) To manage the presentation of a search bar and display search results in iOS 8 and later, instead use [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISearchController).

Read `UISearchController` documentation. There is an example how to create `UISearchController`, not in IB but programmatically.

Comment: Thank you... I also found this while looking around:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html